# Azure VM Servers SQLlaasExtenstion is in transitioning state

Tags: sql, azure, azure-virtual-network

I have a virtual server in azure with sql on it which I enable the backups from within the Azure Portal (which uses the SQL Extension) I need to disable that now as it interfering with my log shipping.

However, I cannot disable the backups or change any of the SQL settings from Azure because the SQL Extension is in a Transitioning status.

I have tried rebooting the server already. The only option I can see is to uninstall the SQL extension from the Azure portal but I don't know how to re-install it as its not on the list of extensions to add. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

[image]